# How to create realistic plastic effect in packaging

Tags: topology

[image: Realistic plastic wrinkles]
How to render realistic plastic packaging with wrinkles same with the image attached

Comment: I'd duplicate the base object and use sculpting to add the wrinkles, then give it a transparent + glossy shader

Answer (score 5):

For the following cloth simulation, the ground plane is set to be a collision object and the box has the 'leather' cloth preset applied.

There is a Sub-Division modifier in the stack below the Cloth Sim modifier, you can place the Sub-D higher up the stack for more detail however this greatly increases the time needed for the calculations to run.

Once the simulation is run, you should have a series of frames to choose from.  Select the one you prefer and ***Apply*** the modifier so that the mesh becomes frozen in that shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into sculpt mode and enable Dyntopo and try to create the affect with some of the brushes. You may want to make a second model for this so that you can create a normal map or bump map.